# Expression are not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}

class Square: NamedShape {
    var sideLength: Double

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 4
    }

    func area() ->  Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }   
}


let test = Square(sideLength: 5.2, name: "my test square")
let a = test.area()
print(a)    //here gives  me the error: Expression are not allowed at the top level
```

Comment: This will actually work perfectly well in a console application. So I would assume this is a Cocoa/CocoaTouch project?

Comment: What kind of project should I create to run swift in it?

Comment: You are asking wrong. What kind of app are you trying to make? An iOS app? An OS X window application? A console application? An Apple Watch app?

Comment: I found my mistake thanks for helping me. I forgot to select swift instead of objective c.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those three lines at the end of the code need to be somewhere else, such as a method in a class. The exception to this is if you're using a playground, which I expect is what you want to do in this case – playgrounds can have loose code just fine.

If you want to put it inside a class, use something like this:

```
class Testy {
    func doStuff() {
        let test = Square(sideLength: 5.2, name: "my test square")
        let a = test.area()
        print(a)
    }
}
```

If you want to call it from an existing method, try using something like `viewDidLoad()` in a view controller.

Comment: This doesn't print me anything in console why?

Comment: If you put it inside a class, you then need to call the class – create a new instance then call `doStuff()` on it.

Comment: I create it inside the Testy class and when i try to call gives me Expected error!

Comment: Perhaps you should post your project somewhere we can all look at.

Comment: What kind of project should I create to run swift in it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I wonder if there are a few basic concepts that you're not familiar with just yet; you might need to back track a few steps to make sure you understand the fundamentals more clearly. [Perhaps start here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform a void function in the top level. `print()` must be nested inside of a class, struct, etc.

Comment: doesn't work if it is nested in a class. If i nest it in a class it gives me the next error at line: "let a = test.area() " Instance member test cannot be used on type Squere

Answer (score 0):

Top-level statements are only allowed in a source file named `main.swift` (all lowercase).